# React + MobX, user Authantication, render error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I'm using `MobX` for my state management, and I also save some information in `localStorage`.

This is what my mobxStore looks like:

```js
const hydrate = create({
    storage: localStorage, // or AsyncStorage in react-native; default: localStorage
    jsonify: false  // if you use AsyncStorage, here shoud be true; default: true
})

export class VendorStore {
    @observable vendor = {};
    @persist @observable.ref loginState = localStorage.getItem('loginState');
}

var vendorStore = new VendorStore()
hydrate('vendorStore', vendorStore).then(() => console.log('vendorStore has been hydrated'))

export default vendorStore
```

The idea is to control page's redirect over `loginState`

This is what my `Dashboard.js` look like this:

```js
if (vendorStore.loginState === false) { return <Redirect to='/signin' /> }
    if (vendorStore.loginState === true) {
        return (
            <div className="Dashboard">
                <h1>Dashboard</h1>
                <Main />
            </div>
        )
```

It's either not working as expected, not redirecting when `loginState` is `false`, or throw me react render error as follows:

```
react-dom.development.js:57 Uncaught Invariant Violation: Dashboard(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null;
```

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: Maybe use if-else statement? I believe your error of empty render might occur because loginState could be `undefined` or something else than `true`/`false`

Answer (score 0):

`If else` do not work  on jsx, try below

```
vendorStore.loginState ?  return (
            <div className="Dashboard">
                <h1>Dashboard</h1>
                <Main />
            </div>
        ): return <Redirect to='/signin' />
```

Comment: I have tried that as well, but the problems seems pretty tricky.  When I used localStorage, even if the state is 'false', it renders the Dashboard instead of Redirect.   But if I do not use localStorage, and set the initial state as false, each time I refresh the page after login, the state switch back to false.

Answer (score 0):

There are few potential issues here.

Firstly, your nested ifs might be causing you issues, try changing to this:

```
if (vendorStore.loginState) {
  return (
    <div className="Dashboard">
      <h1>Dashboard</h1>
      <Main />
    </div>
  )
} else {
  return <Redirect to='/signin' />
}
```

Secondly, if you wish for React to respond to changes in `loginState` then you need to use something which can provide `loginState` as a prop to React. Since vanilla React will only respond to changes in state/props. Try integrating https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react